# Why am I getting notices about File Manager needing to restart?

Tags: notification, filemanager, restart, python3

For a week now I have been getting this notice that File Manger needs to restart with a restart button and cancel button. When I press the restart button nothing happens, that I can tell. The notice doesn't even go away until I close it. Then 10 minutes later the notice is back. Here is a screen shot

[image]

It doesn't give an explanation. It doesn't tell me if something is wrong. No way to report like in other notices.

I have been exploring python but have not installed anything but R. A self paced learning program from Python and made 3.4 my default Python program. That was done after this notice starting popping up though.

I can't even find a program called "File Manager" installed. Can someone tell me where I can find out how to stop this  popping up?

I'm not fond of this File Manager and have looked at other possibilities but haven't had the chance to really look into it. Any suggestions for a replacement file manager are welcome - preferably Windows-like, 2 pane, tree.

Comment: What are these admin extensions?  Did you install these yourself? And Nemo is an excellent replacement.

Comment: As far as I know I haven't added anything to nautilus. The only thing I have installed are mysql which didn't go as smoothlyzes I would have liked but it's Running' but nothing to narutius. Whatever it was it seems to have been taken care of through a update an Monday. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pcmanfm has the option of two pane and tree like in Windows. It is very light and fast to use. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea what was causing the warning but a Security Update on Monday appears to have taken care of it.

thank you, all of you,So much

David